# Missing file from MSDN example for GDI printing

Tags: c++, winapi, sdk, msdn

I am trying to learn to print using `GDI`.

I have searched `MSDN` for resources and found [this](http://archive.msdn.microsoft.com/WindowsPrintSample/Wiki/View.aspx?title=Home&version=9) example.

I like the thought of putting printing in separate thread, and using `GDI` is easier for me to learn than using `XPS API` so I have downloaded the example.

After trying to compile it ( I use `Visual Studio 2008` ) I get this error:

`fatal error C1083: Cannot open include file: 't2embapi.h': No such file or directory`

According to [this](http://archive.msdn.microsoft.com/WindowsPrintSample/Thread/View.aspx?ThreadId=4155), I have found out that I am not the only one facing this problem.

Still, I have tried to `Google` the above error and found [this](http://www.m0interactive.com/archives/2009/08/03/cannot_open_include_files_for_atl_t2embapi_h_while_having_vs2008_installed.html) that indicates me not having the latest `SDK`.

I have searched in `C:\Program Files\Microsoft SDKs\Windows` and found a folder `v6.0A` which indicates that I do not have latest `SDK` installed.

However, [here](http://us.generation-nt.com/answer/font-embedding-header-file-t2embapi-h-help-27112662.html) I have found one post where person with the same problem did not solve it by downloading the latest `SDK` ( although the year that post was made is 2006, still the file was missing then too, and downloading the SDK didn't help-why should anything change now? ).

My question is:

1. Is there a way to get this file ( if I am wrong about downloading the latest `SDK` please correct me ) ?
2. I think that this file has to do something with fonts-is there a way to modify the example so I do not have to use that file?

Thank you for you rime to view this thread and for trying to help.

Best regards.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

T2Embapi.h is supplied by the Windows SDK, it contains declarations for the Font Embedding Services Library to handle embedded OpenType fonts.  Clearly the SDK version you use is too old to have it.  Not exactly sure which version is required, I know that v6.0 doesn't have it but v7.1 does.

There's some sloppiness in the project due to it starting as an XPS sample.  T2Embapi isn't actually required to build the GDI sample.  You can simply delete the #include from stdafx.h.  Also some sloppiness in the Release configuration settings of the project, remove T2embed.lib and XpsPrint.lib from the linker's Additional Dependencies setting.

Comment: Thank you, I will try that and report my results. Best regards.

Comment: I have tried to remove libraries but couldn't find where they are. I have looked on *project*->*Properties*->*Linker*->*Advanced*. The program runs however, but prints to a `XPS` file. Could it be because I do not have a printer? Please apologize for my disturbance, but it seems that you have already tried this application so I ask. Thank you and best regards.

Comment: As noted, they are in the Release configuration settings.  You are probably only looking at the Debug settings.  I haven't looked but assume the program will print to the default printer.  Which commonly is the XPS printer.  Pick another printer as the default.  Use the FILE port to get it to write output to a file instead of the printer.

Comment: Thank you Mr.Passant. Since the program works, and by looking at it I see they did minimal job to illustrate the basics, I think that you are right. Therefore I will accept your answer ( and upvote it ) since the removing of the libraries is another problem irrelevant for this question. Best regards.

Comment: OK, I have found them-I was looking in the wrong place. I have removed them but the file was still sent to the `XPS` even after I change the default printer to *One Note* ( i do not have a printer ). That is not such a big problem, I can still learn from the example. Thank you again and best regards.

Answer (score 2):

Your question is:

*1.
Is there a way to get this file ( if I am wrong about downloading the latest SDK please correct me ) ?*

- The latest version of Windows SDK is for Windows 8.1. [Windows Software Development Kit (SDK) for Windows 8.1](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/windows/desktop/bg162891). However, I think the 't2embapi.h' have already included Windows SDK for Windows 7, because I found the header file in 'C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SDKs\Windows\v7.0A\Include'.

*2.
I think that this file has to do something with fonts-is there a way to modify the example so I do not have to use that file?*

- @Hans Passant has already answered about that.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, I will try to download version 7.1 and report my result. Best regards.

Comment: I can only accept one answer, and Mr.Passant was faster. Thank you for your help, I have upvoted your answer. Best regards.

Comment: Don't worry. I also know that Mr.Passant answer was faster and it was really useful as well as. Thanks for your comment and kindness! :)